# How do I make a program run from console by only its name without putting the whole directory into PATH?

Tags: command-line, putty, cmd.exe, path, conemu

I have set `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\putty.exe`'s default value to `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\putty\putty.exe`. And I can run it from <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> thing (by typing `putty`<kbd>Enter</kbd>), but can't from `cmd.exe`. What am I doing wrong? The bigger picture is I'm trying to run it under `ConEmu`.

Comment: If it's not in the path, Windows doesn't know where to find it.

Comment: But `Win-R` knows. And the question is, How to make `cmd.exe` know too.

Comment: I don't about `conemu`, but `cmd` has an alias facility (see `doskey /?`), which would achieve what you want, though I don't know why you object to modifying `PATH`: if you add it to a [start-up script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404165/how-to-run-a-command-on-command-prompt-startup-in-windows) it won't affect other programs.

Comment: For `putty`, adding the dir to `PATH` will most likely suffice. But considering some arbitrary program (not `putty`) and taking into account Windows way of putting all the files into one directory (no `bin` dir), I don't want to pollute `PATH` with programs, that are not supposed to be run by user. Second, the issue is not with `cmd` particularly, I just would like for it to work everywhere as easy as possible. So, I doubt `doskey` will help solve the problem with `ConEmu`, at least in an easy way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run `putty.exe` from cmd prompt you have to use `start` command! Aliases are not required.

```
start putty
```